# Ошибка при создании цикла, компилятор не видит метод

Tags: java, функции, циклы, компиляция, методы

```
if(cor1() && cor2()){
    System.out.println("eee");
} else {
    System.out.println("noo");
}

static boolean cor1(){
    System.out.println("privet!");
    return false;
}
static boolean cor2(){
    System.out.println("poka!");
    return true;
}
```

Компилятор считает строку со статик за ошибку:

```
Error:(12, 9) java: illegal start of expression
Error:(12, 22) java: ';' expected
Error:(16, 9) java: illegal start of expression
Error:(16, 22) java: ';' expected
```

Понимаю, что вопрос элементарный, но в чем проблема, понять не могу.

Comment: А что ваш статик делает внутри тела метода? (вне класса) Или, что ваш код, делает внутри тела класса? (вне метода)

Comment: Короче, бросайте то по чему вы пытаетесь учить яву, и берите обычную книгу. Должно помочь.

Comment: благодарю Вас! помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

код стоит не в нужном месте

```
if(cor1() && cor2()){
    System.out.println("eee");
} else {
    System.out.println("noo");
}
```

а этот код нужно писать внутри класса

```
static boolean cor1(){
    System.out.println("privet!");
    return false;
}
static boolean cor2(){
    System.out.println("poka!");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода:

```
public class TestCor {

public static void main(String[] args) {

if(cor1() && cor2()){
System.out.println("eee");
} else {
        System.out.println("noo");
        }
}

private static boolean cor1() {
System.out.println("privet!");
return false;
}

private static boolean cor2() {
System.out.println("poka!");
return true;    
}

}
```

Вывод:
run:
privet!
noo
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)